# Как задать сложные грани объекта для столкновения в GameMakerStudio2?

Tags: 2d, game-maker

Как задать более сложные грани объекта для столкновения, чем просто правильный многоугольник

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Уже поздно, но вдруг кто-то тоже будет искать? [Официальные статьи GMS о физике](https://www.yoyogames.com/blog/69/physics-in-gamemaker-studio-2-part-1)

Необходимо создать отдельную **выпуклую** фикстуру, и прикрепить её к объекту.
[image: Так можно создать фикстуру с нужной плотностью и реституцией]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это просто пример, для машины необходимо создать несколько выпуклых фикстур, корпуса, крыши, задней части. А затем прикрепить всё к одному объекту.